# how to change the background of a div smoothly?

Tags: javascript

I have created on script for changing the background of a div continuously after some time intervals as following

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
var images = [ "images/bg-a.jpg","images/bg-b.jpg" , "images/bg-c.jpg" ];
var bg_spans = [ "#bg-a","#bg-b","#bg-c" ];
var currentImage = 0;

function changeBackground() {

    $( '#bdy' ).css( { backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ ++currentImage ] + ')'} );
    for(i=0; i<bg_spans.length; i++ ) {
      if(i==currentImage) {
         $( bg_spans[currentImage]).css ( { background: "#eb5405"} );
         $( bg_spans[currentImage]).css ("border-color","#fff" );
      }
      else {
         $( bg_spans[i]).css ( { background: "#000098"} );
         $( bg_spans[i]).css ("border-color","#000098" );  

      }
    }

    if ( currentImage >= images.length - 1 ) {
        currentImage -= images.length;
    }
}
setInterval( changeBackground, 6000 );  `});
```

here the images are changing after some time intervals. I want some animation effects with this transition. for example images should fade smoothly. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would lay all images on top of eachother. All with opacity 0 except the first. Than jquery animate the opacity from the second to 1 and the first to 0. And so on...